# SignalR hosted on iis works not stable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, signalr, windows-server-2008

I have a problem with signalr 2.2 hosted on iis 7.5 and windows server 2008r2. The problem is when I use my code on widows 7 and iis express signalr methods works perfect, but when I hosted in on this configuration sometimes methods works, but sometimes not. I can't detect any lows of that behavior. I use asp.net mvc3 with .net 4.5.1
Maybe somebody has such issues with signalR? 
The application is simply chat with sending text messages. 
Thanks!

Comment: What are you using here? HubConnection/PersistentConnection ?
can you post your hub/persistent connection code?